# ChartJS data with different intervals

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, chart.js

I have the following ChartJS chart:

- Temperature Data
- of the last 24 hours
- a data point every 5 minutes
  [image: current chart]

I also want to add the rain in a bar chart, but the problem is that it unclear and small when a bar chart has so less width.

Is it possible that i can display the rain every hour and not in a 5 minute interval?
So this is an example what I want to achieve:
[image: bar chart with rain]